# Using EPSG 4326 in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, geocoding, wgs84

I have geocoded a series of addresses using ArcMap 10.5. The Geographic Coordinate System under the properties is:

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_WGS_1984
Datum:  D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree

I just want to confirm that the EPSG code for this is 4326, because when I did some googling I ran into a [lot of EPSG codes for slightly different variations of the projection WGS 84](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/?search=WGS_1984&srtext=Search), and am a bit confused as a result

Comment: Back when 10.5.1 was released, 4326 didn't refer to a "family" of GCS, so you're good.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 4326 is the standard epsg code for latitude/longitude geographic coordinate system using the WGS 84 datum.

Looking at the link you included I think you may be confusing geographic vs projected coordinate systems and datums vs coordinate systems. [A datum is basically a model of the Earth](https://gisgeography.com/wgs84-world-geodetic-system/) (base ellipsoid model combined with geoid model of sea level).

A geographic coordinate system takes the datum to describes locations on that datum in terms of spherical coordinates (e.g. latitude/longitude). EPSG 4326 describes the geographic coordinate system using WGS 84 and the Greenwich meridian.

A projection can then be used to flatten the spherical 3D Earth into a 2D map. They all are built off of a geographic coordinate system and datum.

If you want to read further, [Esri has a good blog post on some of these geodesy nuances](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/coordinate-systems-difference/#:%7E:text=What%27s%20the%20difference%20between%20a%20datum%20and%20a%20geographic%20coordinate,positioned%20relative%20to%20the%20surface.).